# IP as number without usual functions?

Tags: c, sockets, ip

### Context

I would like to know if we can extract the ip information without having to use gethostinfo or getnameinfo etc...

### Part of my code

```
struct sockaddr in_addr;

socklen_t in_len;
int infd;
char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST], sbuf[NI_MAXSERV];
in_len = sizeof in_addr;
infd = accept( fd , &in_addr , &in_len );
```

### Question

I would like to get the client/incoming ip as a number without the usual formatting (eg 3232238637 instead of 192.168.12.45). Is it even possible ?

The source of those functions is obscure as one would wish, so I cannot figure out.

I read that in_addr (sockaddr) could have the information I need. There is no particular reason but discovering the "inners" of those functions and structures.

Thanks !

Comment: Sure. `struct sockaddr` can be cast to `struct sockaddr_in` or `struct in6_addr` (depending on connection type), which contain the IP address. It is difficult to give a more precise answer. Look up the manual for <netinet/in.h>.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. You make it an answer ?

Comment: For IPv6,the correct type is `struct sockaddr_in6`. And the buffer you pass to `accept()` must be large enough to hold such a type. DO NOT declare variables that are `sockaddr` itself, only use `sockaddr` in type-casts when passing `sockaddr_XXX` types to function parameters.

Comment: Why? What is the reason for the constraint 'without the usual functions'? That's why they are provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IPv4:

```
struct sockaddr_in in_addr;
socklen_t in_len = sizeof in_addr;

int infd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &in_addr, &in_len);

// in_addr.sin_addr.s_addr contains the client's IP address
// as a 4-byte integer, in network byte order...
```

For IPv6:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 in_addr;
socklen_t in_len = sizeof in_addr;

int infd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &in_addr, &in_len);

// in_addr.sin6_addr.s6_addr contains the client's IP address
// as a 16-byte array...
```

Comment: Thanks Remy! That is exactly my need :)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to "convert" from the binary representation of an IP address to a string "dotted-decimal" representation, rather than use one of the standard functions, then here is an example of how to do it for an IPV4 address ... if not, please clarify your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main()
{
    struct hostent *he;
    long unsigned nbo;
    he = gethostbyname("localhost");

    nbo = htonl(*((int*)he->h_addr_list[0]));

    printf("h_addr: %lx netbyteorder: %lx  =  %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
      *((int*)he->h_addr_list[0]), nbo,
      (nbo&0xFF000000)>>24, (nbo&0x00FF0000)>>16, (nbo&0x0000FF00)>>8,    
      (nbo&0x000000FF) );
}
```